# Material-UI: How to remove the Drawer in certain routes when using with react-router-dom?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, material-ui, react-router-dom

I put all routes as children of Material UI `Drawer` and use as props. Since the login page cant have the `Drawer`, how can I structure the login route so that it doesn't include the drawer?

What I'm trying now joins everything together

```
function App(props) {
  const { history } = props;
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Route path="/" exact component={Login} />
      <Drawer history={history}>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/kids" component={Listing} />
          <Route path="/register" component={Register} />
        </Switch>
      </Drawer>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a wrapper of MUI's `Drawer` that conditionally renders the `Drawer` based on the current route. For example:

```js
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

function isAuthRoute(pathname: string) {
  return pathname === "/" || pathname === "/register";
}

function MyDrawer() {
  const location = useLocation();

  if (isAuthRoute(location.pathname)) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <Drawer>
      {...}
    </Drawer>
  );
}
```

Then include `MyDrawer` in every page. You can create a `Layout` component to streamline that process:

```js
function Layout({ children }) {
  return (
    <>
      {children}
      <MyDrawer />
    </>
  )
}

function LoginPage() {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <LoginContent />
    </Layout>
  )
}

function ListingPage() {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <ListingContent />
    </Layout>
  )
}
```

Finally in your App, declare the `Route`s as normal, the `Drawer` inside will know when to render correctly.

```js
export default function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact component={LoginPage} />
        <Route path="/kids" component={ListingPage} />
        <Route path="/register" component={RegisterPage} />
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```